# Django Custom User Model Failes to encrypt password from admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-custom-user, django-custom-field

I have created a custom user model by inheriting AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin and also created a Custom Manager for creating users and superuser. But when I try to add new user from Django admin site, it fails to encrypt the password field and keeps the plain text.

[image]

But when I request from the client site by using the Serializer's create function it works fine.

Custom Model Class Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
from .managers import UserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   """
   Responsible for handleing App user's data
   """
   username = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_authority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_general_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   timestamps = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   update_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   objects = UserManager()

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Custom Manager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
      """
      Creates and saves a new user
      """
      user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **kwargs)
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user


  def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
      """
      For superusers registration
      """
      user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
      user.is_staff = True
      user.is_superuser = True
      user.is_active = True
      user.is_authority = True
      user.save(using=self._db)

      return user
```

Serialize Class which works fine:

```
class UserCommonDetailSerializers(UserAdminDetailSerializers):
"""
Responsible for serializing user's detail data
"""
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
is_active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
is_staff = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
is_authority = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
is_general_user = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = (
        'url', 
        'id', 
        'username',
        'email', 
        'first_name',
        'last_name', 
        'password',
        'is_active', 
        'is_staff', 
        'is_authority',
        'is_general_user')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email=validated_data['email'], 
        password=validated_data['password'])
    return user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are implementing your own user model then you must also implement custom user admin class as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

Example:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    list_filter = ["is_staff"]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {"fields": ["username", "email", "password"]}),
        (
            "Other info",
            {
                "fields": [
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name",
                ],
            },
        ),
    ]
    add_fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    "username",
                    "email",
                    "first_name",
                    "last_name",
                    "password1",
                    "password2",
                ]
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Note the use of `password1` and `password2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ordering = ['id']
    list_display = ['email']
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined','last_login')
    fieldsets = (
        (_("User Details"), {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_("Account Details"), {'fields': ('date_joined', 'last_login')}),
        (_("Permission"), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        ("User Details", {'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}),
        ("Permission", {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_admin')}),
    )


admin.site.register(get_user_model(), AccountAdmin)
```

Comment: Got it, but why this "_" here?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/  details here